# How can i put together a sensible SQL query taken from a user form entry?

Tags: android, sql

I'm in the middle of putting together a button function together that runs an SQL query together but i feel like i could be doing it in a much more efficent way.

My form looks like this:

[image]

and my code to run the view is:

```
    public void customViewAction(View view){

    String QueryFull = null;
    String QueryCostFull = null;
    String QueryStart = "SELECT * FROM expenses ";
    String QueryCostStart = "SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM expenses ";

    if(allTimeButton.isSelected() && descriptionSpinner.getSelectedItem().equals("All")){
        QueryFull = QueryStart+";";
        QueryCostFull = QueryCostStart+";";
    }else if (allTimeButton.isSelected() && !descriptionSpinner.getSelectedItem().equals("All")){
        QueryFull = QueryStart+"WHERE Description = " + "'"+(String)descriptionSpinner.getSelectedItem()+"';";
        QueryCostFull = QueryCostStart+"WHERE Description = " + "'"+(String)descriptionSpinner.getSelectedItem()+"';";
    }else if (betweenButton.isSelected() && descriptionSpinner.getSelectedItem().equals("All")){
        QueryFull = QueryStart+"WHERE Purchase_Date between '"+fromDate+"' AND '"+toDate+"';";
        QueryCostFull= QueryCostStart+"WHERE Purchase_Date between '"+fromDate+"' AND '"+toDate+"';";
    }else if (betweenButton.isSelected() && !descriptionSpinner.getSelectedItem().equals("All")){
        QueryFull = QueryStart+"WHERE Purchase_Date between '"+fromDate+"' AND '"+toDate+"' AND Description = '" + (String)descriptionSpinner.getSelectedItem()+"';";
        QueryCostFull = QueryCostStart+"WHERE Purchase_Date between '"+fromDate+"' AND '"+toDate+"' AND Description = '" + (String)descriptionSpinner.getSelectedItem()+"';";
    }
}
```

I'm yet to add the else if's that will take into account the minimum and max prices and i realise its going to start getting pretty messy, so I'm wondering you guys can suggest smarter and more efficient ways of putting together an SQL query to run?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach to this solution is to have four variables declared to the min/max of the values allowed by your application:

```
String dateMin = '01-01-2000';
String dateMax = datetime.today();
```

Then, when you read data in from the form, update these variables where appropriate, i.e.,

```
if (dateRangeIsSelected) {
    dateMin = fromDate;
    dateMax = toDate;
}
```

This way, you're query will always, structurally, be the same - just format it with those 4 variables.

```
' ... WHERE PurchaseDate between ' + dateMin + ' AND ' + dateMax ' ... '
```

Comment: hmm sorry,  not quite catching what you're trying to say?

Comment: but then if datRange isnt selected it would be ' ... WHERE PurchaseDate between ' + null + ' AND ' + null ' ... ' ?? and that would cause an error right?

Comment: No, that's why you intially set the variables manually to the upper and lower bounds. If the date range is never selected, the query would be `WHERE PurchaseDate between 01-01-2000 AND datetime.today()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java dev so double-check my syntax. But below is one way to handle the logic more sustainably. Only add filters when you need them (note the ! for "All" and the 1=1 which is always true). And don't write the same code twice.

```
String strSelectAll = "SELECT * ";
String strSelectSum = "SELECT SUM(Cost) ";
String strFrom = "FROM expenses WHERE 1=1 ";
String strWhere = null;

if(!descriptionSpinner.getSelectedItem().equals("All")){
strWhere = strWhere + "' AND Description = '" + (String)descriptionSpinner.getSelectedItem() + "' ";
}

if(betweenButton.isSelected()) {  
    strWhere = strWhere + " And Purchase_Date between '" + fromDate + "' AND '" + toDate + "' ";
}

strWhere = strWhere + "' AND Cost between " + minCost + " AND " + maxCost;

strSelectAll = strSelectAll + strFrom + strWhere + ";";
strSelectSum = strSelectSum + strFrom + strWhere + ";";
```

Comment: thanks for this, would this run correctly if there was no input for cost? or if only one of the costs were entered?

Comment: if cost is optional, wrap it into another if statement. do a separate one for min and max, and use `>=` and `<=`, instead of `between`. Those operators do identical things when a query is compiled, `between` is just a shorthand version.